# token from microsoft graph is sometimes "corrupted"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Weird issue.

I have a microsft saas app who asks for different permissions (directory.readWrite, file.readWrite Mail... etc) at the admin consent page.

After an admin gave his consent, my app acquires token and start doing what is should.

The thing is that sometimes I get token without "roles" section (I decoded the access token with jwt decoder and saw it was missing..)

and when it is missing then if I try to get users details (for instance) then I get 401 status code:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2019-04-10T16:50:28",
            "request-id": "fa93e103-6c0e-48cd-af06-008a52762aaa"
        },
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
}
```

And that make sense...

How come that the token sometimes contains the "roles" section with all my app permissions and sometimes not? is it Microsoft issue? is there a workaround?

It isn't a specific tenant problem as if I try again after failure with the same tenant then it might work just fine..

Any thoughts?

Comment: That sounds pretty weird. How often does it happen?

Comment: weird indeed.. could you share some more info on code used to acquire token.. a good and a bad token (minus sensitive info).. also does it happen right after admin consent? because then it could just be an initial lag issue as reported in a very similar thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800659/azure-ad-missing-roles-claim-in-app-only-tokens

Comment: Thank you both for commenting. It actually does happen right after admin consent, and the symptoms described in the post you provided seems just like my issue so I'm guessing it is just initial lag. So the solution should be to simply keep acquiring token until I'm getting a valid one? Thanks.

Comment: What endpoint are you using. The V1 or V2 version? The protocol changed a bit.